# Debugging Symfony3 with built in server, Xdebug 2.5 and PhpStorm 2017 doesn't stop at breakpoint

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to debug my Symfony3 app with the built in server but it doesn't stop at breakpoint.

So I launch my app with `bin/console server:run --env=dev` and I can access it through the following URL: `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Here is what I have done so far :

1. PHP 5.6.31 installation from homebrew
2. Xdebug installation and configuration : seems OK from my `phpinfo()`

   [image: xdebug phpinfo]
3. PhpStorm setup of the PHP CLI Interpreter configuration the one I get when I do a `php -v`
4. PhpStorm debug configuration: can accept external connection port 9000
5. PhpStorm server config: host => `127.0.0.1` port `8000` (I tried with and without path mapping)
6. PhpStorm setup of the PHP remote debug configuration : use of previous PHP server, ideKEY `PHPSTORM`
7. Use of the "Xdebug Helper" Chrome addon
8. Here is what my xdebug log shows

   [image: xdebug log]

What am I doing wrong?

I previously had and a php version 5.6.30 and I can see in the log that there is a `xdebug:language_version="5.6.30"` -- could there be a conflict from this previous installation?

I think I read all the post relate to this subject but I found only one that was actually talking of the built in server.

Comment: ¿Did you tried analising your full phpinfo using this tool? https://xdebug.org/wizard.php it helped me sometimes.

Comment: Have you tried to use "Break at first line in PHP scripts" option of PHPSTORM?

Comment: 1) You are on Mac. Check who actually listens on TCP 9000 port (`sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`). Based on your xdebug log it most likely will be php-fpm. 2) Based on that -- please change xdebug port from 9000 to be 9001 in both PhpStorm and xdebug (php.ini) settings and try again (web server restart required). 3) Ensure that PhpStorm is listening on xdebug port (will be done when you initiate Debug from IDE via "Debug" button .. or use that "phone handle" icon manually). You can verify that with command from #1.

Comment: @sh4 : yes tried and no pb from them

Comment: @svgrafov : Tried that too but it's not working either

Comment: @LazyOne : excuse my CapsLock but THANK YOU!!!!!!! That's indeed that! omg I tried changing the port but didn't stop and restart listening so the port stayed at 9000 instead of 9001... :'(    Thanks to your command, I was able to identify that : you're the best man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)! On Mac the port 9000 is used by php-fpm if installed (which was my case). So xdebug port has to be changed to another one like 9001 on both php.ini config and PHPSTORM Xdebug config. Don't forget like me to stop and restart listening de debug for the change to be activated :p

Comment: Just spent half an hour trying to figure this out until I read this and realized I hadn't changed the PHPSTORM debug port.